# Custom Navigation bar Error

Tags: ios, xcode, uinavigationbar

I'm trying to customise navigation bar in iOS 7. I create custom class that is subclass of UINavigationBar. And there I make the following changes:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [self setTranslucent:YES];
        [self setAlpha:0.6f];
    }
return self;
}
```

And there is no any changes, I set custom class in interface builder. What should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to override initWithCoder, not initWithFrame, if You are using storyboard to create UINavigationBar.
In situations like that try to set breakpoint to method and check it this method get called at least

Answer (score 0):

If you are using your custom view in IB, you should also override `awakeFromNib` and do some init there as well. In your code, it could be:

```
- (instancetype)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
     self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
     if (self) {
        [self setup];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)awakeFromNib {
    [self setup];
}

-(void)setup {
     [self setBarTintColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
     [self setTranslucent:YES];
     [self setAlpha:0.6f];
}
```